# Variable scope in async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to access a variable that i declared inside in an async function. Like this:

```
exports.startTheBasketEngine = async (username, password, domainData) => {
    const parse = domainData.auctionUrl.split("-")
    var domainName = parse[0]

    const stringIsIncluded = await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log(domainName)
     });
}
```

The console.log line is returning that error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: domainName is not defined
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Works for me locally. We need to see more code to evaluate the problem. What's in page.evaluate() ?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `await page.evaluate((dName) => { console.log(dName); }, domainName);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Puppeteer.

According to the [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args), the `.evaluate()` takes more arguments. All arguments, starting from the second, will be passed to the `pageFunction`. So try something like this:

```
var domainName = parse[0]

const stringIsIncluded = await page.evaluate((dName) => {
    console.log(dName);
 }, domainName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the value to evaluate, it is executed in a separate context, see: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

```js
const stringIsIncluded = await page.evaluate((domainName) => {
    console.log(domainName)
}, domainName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your variable:

```
 const stringIsIncluded = await page.evaluate((domainName) => {
    console.log(domainName)
 }, domainName);
```